# From SFP+ to SFP + Juniper EX4200 specific question

Tags: juniper-ex, sfp

Say we have a Juniper EX4200 with the 4x 1G SFP uplink module, with 1G transceivers, and another switch with 10G SFP+ downlinks. Can we connect the 10G SFP+ downlinks of one switch to the 1G SFP uplinks of the other switch and expect them to be detected as 1G?

Also, does installing an uplink module in an EX4200 cancels some of the other 48 built-in ports, as with the older EX3200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  There is no multi-speed option in 1/10G optics for Juniper (or Cisco or most others).  That said, you can likely just put another 1GE SFP optic into the SFP+ slot currently occupied by the 10G SFP+ on the switch side and it ought to work.

Comment: That's actually not quite true.  There are in fact 1/10G SFP+ modules available, only they aren't currently supported by Juniper.  Finisar are an OEM: https://www.finisar.com/optical-transceivers/ftlx8574d3bcv and Brocade have supported them for some years.

Comment: Huh - interesting!  I know that there used to be something similar in the lower-end Catalyst line a long time ago that would do GE-SX or 100FX but had never heard of 1+10 in a single optic.  I'll edit my answer accordingly - thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, does installing an uplink module in an EX4200 cancels some of
>   the other 48 built-in ports, as with the older EX3200?

No, the EX4200 allows all 48 fixed interfaces to operate along with the uplink module, unlike the 3200, which disables the last four interfaces.

This is due to the 4200 having 3x PFEs compared with the 2 built into the 3200.